How do I calculate shipping for different product types?
I'm using Commerce Core and Commerce shipping modules on Drupal 10.
I have 5 product types: Accessories, Pads, Clocks, Cables, Merchandies.
I'd like to charge the following for delivery:
Accessories = £5 shipping
Pads = £10 shipping
Clocks = £25 shipping
Cables = £10 shipping
Merchandise = £10 shipping.
I've created three Shipping methods Delivery £5, Delivery £10 and delivery £25 and have set conditions for each of these shipping methods to match the respective product type.
This works great, so for example if a customer adds an accessorie the shipping method "Delivery £5" is displayed for them. If they add a clock the shipping method "Delivery £25" is displayed for them.
The problem is, if they add an accessorie and a clock to their cart, both shipping methods "Delivery £5" and "Delivery £25" are displayed. Obvoisuly I want the checkout to calculate the shipping of both items £25+£5 = £30. I don't want it to display two seperate options as they will just choose the £5 option.
This seems so simple but I have spent ages trying to work out how to do this.
Thank you!

Yeah, the issue you're experiencing is that flat rate definitions are all intended to be one or the other, not additive. To achieve logic like this, you'd really need a custom shipping method plugin. I'm not entirely sure how we'd accomplish something like you're suggesting as a feature within Commerce Shipping itself, but this would make a fine feature request.
